# Switch User won't work in Xfce

Tags: arch-linux, users, xfce

I'm trying to do Switch User in action buttons but gets me following error :

> **Unable to start new display**
>
> GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name
>   org.gnome.DisplayManager was not provided by any .service files

Comment: maybe adding some version number, and what you have tried so far could help also.

Comment: What display manager do you use (the program where you log in: xdm, gdm, kdm, lightdm, wdm, …)?

Comment: @Gilles I'm using Slim.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge the `Switch users` functionality in Xfce does not support `slim`. Try a different DM like `lightdm`.